# Android- cant get String from Resources for Static field- Non-static Method getResources cannot be referenced from a static-context"

Tags: java, android, android-resources, static-members

I passed images and text in Grid view with launcherIcons class. As the below codes, works fine.
But I want to change the String as

```
new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,getResources().getString(R.string.hello))
```

I want to get string from Resources(R.string.hello) and when implement getResources warning **"Non-static Method getResources cannot be referenced from a static-context"**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    String Activity="MainActivity";
    Context activity_context=MainActivity.this;
    static final LauncherIcon[] ICONS = {
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Hello"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "About me"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Venky"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Noctilien"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Metro"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "RER"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Bus"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Metro"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "RER"),
            new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Bus"),

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //blah blah.............


}
```

LauncherIcon Class

```
   static class LauncherIcon {
        final String text;
        final int imgId;
        //final String map;

        public LauncherIcon(int imgId, String text) {
            super();
            this.imgId = imgId;
            this.text = text;
          //  this.map = map;
        }

    }
```

How to use getResources String in there?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If any one gives downvote to my question. please clear your view why you gives downvote?

Comment: why have you declared your array as static? What is the need of static class?

Comment: Have you tried with the context? activity_context.getResources().getString(R.string.hello)

Comment: @Chol no need for that. @ Venkatesh Sekvam Also context is available once activity is created. So move the initialization of context in onCreate. Remove static from the array. Launcher icon looks like a model class can be a separate class in case you have that as a inner class of activity

Comment: The error message is not clear enough ? You can't call a non-static method from a static block ...

Comment: @VenkateshSelvam: Is `LauncherIcon ` is inner-class of `MainActivity ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things I'd change is remove the `static` in your `LauncherIcon` class, and it could be like this :

```
public class LauncherIcon {
final String text;
final int imgId;
    public LauncherIcon(int imgId, String text) {
        super();
        this.imgId = imgId;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Then you create the array of `LauncherIcons` without `static` as follows :

```
LauncherIcon[] ICONS = {
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Hello"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "About me"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Venky"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Noctilien"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Metro"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "RER"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Bus"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Metro"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "RER"),
        new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Bus"),

};
```

> I passed images and text in Grid view with launcherIcons class. As the below codes, works fine. But I want to change the String as :
>
> new LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,getResources().getString(R.string.hello));

If you get error doing this, you can call it doing  (the first way if you change it as my answer should work):

```
LauncherIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, YOURCONTEXT.getResources().getString(R.string.hello));
```